# Defining Custom Powershell Objects

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

There are many different ways to create objects in Powershell. I am posting this as a challenge to create objects purely in Powerhell. I am looking for a way to create objects using Add-Type that pass these requirements:

1. Strongly-Typed object properties
2. Instantiated, using: `New-Object`, `[My.Object]::New()`, `[My.Object]@{'Property'='Value'}`
3. Part of a custom Namespace (i.e [My.Object])
4. Can be type-checked. Example: `$myVar -is [My.Object]`

I know dll's can be created in Visual Studio that would accomplish this, but I am looking for a purely Powershell way to create objects.

Here is the closest example I have that satisfy the rules above:

```
PS C:\> $memberDef = @"
public String myString { get; set; }
public int myInt { get; set; }
"@

PS C:\> Add-Type -Namespace "My.Namespace" -Name "Object" -MemberDefinition $memberDef

PS C:\> $myObj = [My.Namespace.Object]@{'myString'='Foo'; 'myInt'=42}
PS C:\> $myObj

myString myInt
-------- -----
Foo         42
```

With that said, are there other (Possibly better) ways to create objects that look, feel, and act like native Powershell objects?

### Examples that do not satisfy all rules

Weakly-Typed object properties:

```
PS C:\> $myObj = "" | Select-Object -Property myString, myInt

PS C:\> $myObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'myString'='foo'; 'myInt'=42}


PS C:\> $myObj = @{}; $myObj.myString = 'foo'; $myObj.myInt = 42

PS C:\> $myObj.myInt = "This should result in an error."
```

Objects without namespaces:

```
PS C:\> $typeDef = @"
public class myObject {
   public string myString { get; set; }
   public int myInt { get; set; }
}
"@
PS C:\> Add-Type -TypeDefinition $typeDef
PS C:\> $myObj = [myObject]::new()

PS C:\> $myObj = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'myString'='foo'; 'myInt'=42}
PS C:\> $myObj.PSObject.TypeNames.Insert(0, "myObject")
```

Comment: I like what you're getting at.  I don't think what you're asking for is possible in pure PowerShell.  Here's the best I know: https://powershellstation.com/2016/05/22/custom-objects-and-pstypename/

Comment: The example I posted above pretty much covers all the rules. But I am sure there are some things that still need to be done to make it like a native Powershell object. Ah yes, your link for PSTypeName is good, it adds a type name so you can use format.ps1xml formats against them. I will add it to the above examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best way I have found to create an object in Powershell that is part of a namespace and covers all the rules above.

```
PS C:\> $memberDef = @"
public String myString { get; set; }
public int myInt { get; set; }
"@

PS C:\> Add-Type -Namespace "My.Namespace" -Name "Object" -MemberDefinition $memberDef

PS C:\> $myObj = [My.Namespace.Object]@{'myString'='Foo'; 'myInt'=42}
PS C:\> $myObj

myString myInt
-------- -----
Foo         42
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Strongly-Typed object

The closest you're gonna get is an explicitly typed variable. This can be accomplished by casting the *variable* itself during assignment:

```
PS C:\> [My.Namespace.Object]$myObj = [My.Namespace.Object]@{'myString'='Foo'; 'myInt'=42}
PS C:\> $myObj = 123
Cannot convert the "123" value of type "System.Int32" to type "My.Namespace.Object".
At line:1 char:1
+ $myObj = 123
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

As you can see, this causes `$myObj` to only accept new assignments that can be implicitly converted to the type.

Comment: When I was writing the question, I was looking for strongly-typed object properties. But you are correct, the best example above does prevent objects that can't be cast to this type from being assigned. I edited my question to be more specific. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: What is the actual question here? What does "Strongly-type object properties" mean exactly?

Comment: The question is how to better make a custom object purely in Powershell, one that acts just like a native powershell object. As for "Strongly-typed object properties", I am looking for objects with properties that cannot change type (see Weakly-Typed object properties examples above.)

Comment: You can't, unless you compile a class like in your first example, or (in version 5.0+) define a class and create a `::new()` instance